# Update existing values in Cassandra 3.0 to Uppercase

Tags: cassandra

I have requirement to update existing values in Cassandra 3.0 to Uppercase.
Its for all rows and for a single column of type text

I would need to do this update all the way to production and want the least intrusive/ iterative way of doing it as some of environment will be update by different team. This will be a one time task

Thanks for help,Appreciate your time

Neha
Cassandra Newbie

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra does not offer native support for this kind of work. You will need to look at either writting your own application that reads and re-insert with upercase. For large scale cluster, you will want to look at using spark on cassandra. Spark is often use on top of Cassandra to perform some analytics, or data migration, like you are doing.

Comment: UPDATE schema.table set column = 'OTHER' WHERE column = 'other'; How about something like this ? Its very small dataset. I can use cqslsh client to do this work. But by query is giving error. InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Some partition key parts are missing: